# What does なくた mean in 理解されなくたっていい?

Tags: grammar, parsing

I am reading 宇宙よりも遠い場所. Right off the beginning comes a sentence: "誰にも理解されなくたっていい".

I am sure it means "It is OK that it is not understood by anybody". However, the されなくた puzzles me:

1. Shouldn't ない past form be なかった?
2. I google 理解されなくた and Google only returns 理解されなくて.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are parsing the sentence incorrectly.

> 「誰{だれ}にも理解{りかい}されなく**たって**いい。」

It is されなく + たって and not され + なくた.

「理解されなく」 is the negative passive-voice form -- "not being understood".

「たって」 is a colloquial way of saying 「ても」.  You have surely encountered 「～～てもいい」 before, I presume.

> "I would not care (even) if no one understood me."

Or more literally,

> "I would not care (even) if I am not understood by anyone."