# 「戦って勝たなくたっていい..」

Tags: meaning, contractions, anime

In this YouTube video from an anime [暗殺教室 渚 殺気② t=44s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFuiax-2QRU&t=44) what I hear the character is saying is the following:

> 戦{たたか}って勝{か}たな**くたって**いい、殺{ころ}せば勝｛か｝ちなんだ。

I don't understand where the part in bold comes from.

I would guess that it is some variation of the following sentence, but with some additional nuance.

> 戦って勝たなくていい、殺せば勝ちなんだ。

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60511/1478

Comment: So it seems, thank you snailcar!